# Rearranging spaces in macOS in a more "automatic" fashion

Tags: shortcut, script, spaces, mission-control, automation

I'm looking for a way to swap Mission Control space *n* to space *m*, by means of a keyboard shortcut or a terminal command as to make this process more automated/automate-able. With this, I am not trying to *switch* from one space to another, but to perform an action that rearranges the ordening of the active spaces. When Mission Control is open, you can do this with the mouse by dragging for example the "Space 1" text to the position of "Space 2". Is there a way to achieve this in a more "automatic" fashion? (preferably not using automator mouse actions)

Comment: While the title asks for something quite general, I'm also satisfied with a more simple solution that swaps a spaces with the space next to it.

Comment: Why not just set up key commands to go to specific Spaces & use those. Then you'll actually learn where things are & muscle-memory takes over, rather than ...swipe, swipe, swipe, oh dammmit, too far, swipe back...

Comment: I have certain spaces designated for certain usages. Sometimes I like to put other spaces I use more close to them, or maybe put a space somewhere further done if I want to rest a project for a while but come back to it's window configuration/app state. The mouse method is quite cumbersome for this and additionally error prone. Furthermore, I don't find it preferable to remember the content of my spaces in an exact manner, so I would rather not engage with the number muscle memory but simply switch right/left with the arrow keys between related tasks. Other personal workflow reasons apply too

Comment: Never used it myself, but it looks like it does what you want, for a price - https://totalspaces.binaryage.com/

Comment: @NeilSmithline How much I do love that 3D cube, installing a separate application with a ton of (unwanted) features seems overkill to me, especially when it costs money.  (+ I don't directly see how it would solve my problem from what it offers)